# Postfix and PHP scripts From Address

Tags: php, postfix

I have some PHP scripts that email users their password when needed. The problem I'm facing is that the PHP sends the email as "www-data ". My question here is how to configure postfix so my PHP scripts are authenticated and have a proper From Address. I know I can't do that from the scripts but that's considered forgery right?

Cheers

Comment: Emails their password?!  Does that mean you are storing passwords in plain text?  Does that mean you don't mind sending passwords in the clear?  I have no idea about Postfix, but your application design is pretty concerning if you are sending passwords over email.

Comment: BTW, consider using Zend_Mail or PHPMailer instead of trying to handle all the mail stuff yourself.

Comment: No i'm not storing plain text password. That password recovery creates a new one that is send to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Postfix issue. Set From: in [PHP mail function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

Comment: So with a From header email providers won't mark me as spam?

Comment: There are hundreds of reasons for mails to be marked as spam. More probable is that your DNS settings are wrong: Hostname, EHLO name, IP, Reverse-DNS. Hard to tell without more information.

Comment: @sw0x2A solves my problem for now, cheers

Comment: @sw0x2A it's not that the email im sending right now are marked as spam i just like to think ahead and prevent that. Any tips on how to do it?

Comment: Nothing that I can explain in 600 characters. For a first overview have a look at this guidelines: http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/mail/postmaster/basics/postmaster-15.html